# CSS Show active element above the div with overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

I have a scrolling pane div with overflow:hidden. Please check it [here](http://pixeli.ca/works/contour). There are products as images with captions shown in the scrolling pane. When I move mouse cursor over a product div, it gets light-yellow background and changes its height - I just add a class to the div using jQuery and it works fine. The problem I need to solve some way is to show the expanded div for the active product as a separate div that appears above the scrolling pane, though now it appears inside that pane and extends it in its height. I want to make it look in similar way to [this one](http://www.ikea.com/ru/ru/catalog/categories/departments/workspaces/18960/). Here you move mouse cursor over the product and get an extended div showing you details. Surely, my task is a little harder because of that scrolling pane.

Comment: There's no easy way to do this. Thinking off the top of my head, you probably need to rip/clone the entire product `div` from its original position in the HTML structure, then AP it before doing the hightlighting. This could get very ugly very quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't be too difficult if you use the [.offset() method](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) on hover of a `.product`.  What you can do is the following:

1. In your `.product` hover event handler, get the offset of the product.  This will give you the position of your product in relation to the document.
2. Next create your overlay product information div and append it directly to the `<body>`.
3. Set the overlay div to position: absolute and use the values returned from the offset call to position it.
4. Lastly make sure your overlay has a higher z-index than the scrolling pane and you should be in business.